# Shockwave Flash is not working on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, crash, plugins, extension

I get the same problem every time on my Chrome. When I try to open a site with Flash the plugin crashes and I am unable to use the site, like YouTube.

The same thing happens on Microsoft Edge. The problem is solved temporarily if I delete my account on Chrome and I sign in back, but that isn't a permanent fix.

It means I have some kind of problem with my account.

The extensions I have:

- Adblock Plus
- Google Docs
- Google Docs Office
- Google PDF Viewer
- Google play movies, music, presentation and tables
- Payback
- Vaysor

The plugins:

- Chrome PDF Viewer
- Widevine Content Decryption Module
- Native Client
- Adobe Flash Player

Is there anything suspicious? I really don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, Chrome comes with its own Flash-gizmo as a plugin and therefore you don't even really need the standalone version of Flash on your machine. Now I can't speak the same about MS Edge as I have no idea. Now if the plugin for Chrome fails, disable it and see what happens (many YouTube videos are HTML5 based and probably don't need Flash). If not that, try updating Chrome.

Comment: I have tried doing both of it, disabling the adobe flash player plugin and updating Chrome. The YouTube site freezes and I get a message that it can't load.

Comment: You mentioned signing out of your account. Try to sign out and stay signed out and then go to YouTube. If it works, then your account is obviously corrupted and the next measure would be to figure out how to fix a corrupted account. (This may/may not help - https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/S0R5qzYxJ88)